# Compare list of list from lines

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

output using parted -l

```
Model: ATA KINGSTON SH103S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1024MB  1023MB  primary   ext4         boot
 2      1026MB  120GB   119GB   extended
 5      1026MB  120GB   119GB   logical                lvm


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00W (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  ext4         primary


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/system-root: 103GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  103GB  103GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/system-swap: 16.4GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  16.4GB  16.4GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

output using parted -lm

```
BYT;
/dev/sda:120GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA KINGSTON SH103S3:;
1:1049kB:1024MB:1023MB:ext4::boot;
2:1026MB:120GB:119GB:::;
5:1026MB:120GB:119GB:::lvm;

BYT;
/dev/sdb:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00W:;
1:1049kB:1000GB:1000GB:ext4:primary:;

BYT;
/dev/mapper/system-root:103GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:103GB:103GB:ext4::;

BYT;
/dev/mapper/system-swap:16.4GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:16.4GB:16.4GB:linux-swap(v1)::;
```

I have text like this, what i would like to do is

Create loop for disk in each lines start with "Model:"

Then inside for loop 3 time, that get 3 item,
If line start with Model :
Disk[i].model = line
Elif line start with Disk
Disk[i].size = line
Elif line start with " 1"
Disk[i].partition = line

So next

I can find which partition have keyword boot

For disk in disk[i]

If disk[i].partition contain "boot"
DiskContainOs = disk[i].model.

Is it right using double for loop like this?

```
def getMainDisk():
    #get disk info using "parted -lm" sample like from outputParted
    #for loop to find "BYT;"
    #if found then get next 2 line
    disk = []
    for i, line in enumerate(outputParted.splitlines()):
        if line.startswith("BYT;"):
            disk.append([])
            
            #for j loop next 2 line after found BYT;
            for j in outputParted.splitlines()[i+0:i+1]:
                disk[i].append(j)
            
            #compare disk if have "boot" keyword then append disk[x] to Maindisk

    # print (Maindisk)
```

got error :

```
line 265, in getMainDisk
    disk[i].append(j)
IndexError: list index out of range
root@pc:~#
```

any idea?

Comment: This looks like the output from GNU Parted, which has an option `-m` to give machine parseable output which you might find easier to handle (Newer versions also have a `-j` JSON output option). It gives out single line, colon separated output for each disk and lines for each of its partitions.

Comment: i cant update this package as this not my own pc , just only can use -m

Answer (score 0):

I answer my self , by not using nested for loop

because the output of parted is constant will show 2 physical drive at first, and also my system also constantly only have 2 drive, and more importantly i just want to know which disk contain operating system, which have keyword boot. so i just using if else, inside for loop.

Thanks All.

```
def getMainDisk():
    outputParted = subprocess.check_output(['parted', '-lm'])
    outputParted = outputParted.decode('utf-8')
    # print(outputParted)
    # print(outputParted)

    disk = []
    for i, line in enumerate(outputParted.splitlines()):
        if 'BYT' in line:
            # print(line)
            print(i)
            # print(outputParted.splitlines()[i+1])
            # print(outputParted.splitlines()[i+1].split(':')[0])
            diskName = outputParted.splitlines()[i+1].split(':')[6]
            diskSize = outputParted.splitlines()[i+1].split(':')[1]
            lineContainboot = outputParted.splitlines()[i+2]
            # print(lineContainboot)
            if 'boot' in lineContainboot:
                # print(lineContainboot)
                # print(lineContainboot.split(':')[0])
                disk.append(diskName)
                disk.append(diskSize)
                print(disk)
                print('xx')
                r = disk[0] + ' ' + disk[1]
                return r
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```